# Creating a matplotlib multi-series line plot with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, line

I want to create a multi series line plot showing how the occurrences of a data-frame element change over time:

I have two lists in which I have joined in a dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
{'Date': datelist,
 'Category': catlist
})
```

I have then grouped the dataframe to show the counts of each occurrence over time:

```
df = df.groupby(['Date', 'Category']).size()
print df
```

This returns something that looks like this:

```
 Date        Category        
 13/02/2018  clean          2
             suspicious     1
 14/02/2018  clean          2
 19/02/2018  clean          2
```

I now want to create a multi-series line plot for each category type, showing how the count changes over date.

I'm really not sure how to do this using matplotlib

Answer (score 2):

You can try with:

```
plot_df = df.unstack('Category')
plot_df.index = pd.PeriodIndex(plot_df.index.tolist(), freq='D')
plot_df.plot()
plt.show()
```

Or with `subplot`:

```
plot_df.plot(subplots=True)
```

Example: 
For the dataframe:

```
Date        Category
13/02/2018  clean
13/02/2018  clean
13/02/2018  suspicious
14/02/2018  clean
14/02/2018  clean
19/02/2018  clean
19/02/2018  clean
14/02/2018  suspicious
13/02/2018  suspicious
14/02/2018  clean
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, is there a reason why it only plots the one category and only plots a single date from the list?

Comment: What do you mean? It can happen that if a category is constant, you dont see it in the graph

Comment: My main issue now is that the Dates on the X axes Appear as the following "13 Feb 18", "14", "15" - why is the full date not shown?

Comment: For the suspicious category most likely is because it is constant, or just for a day. Let me check for the date

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166252/discussion-between-samolivercz-and-joe).

Answer (score 0):

```
categories = df.Category.unique()   #to find unique categories
f,plots = plt.subplots(1,categories.len())   #generate subplot grid (1xNo. of unique categories)
for i, category in enumerate(categories):
    temp = df['Category'==category]   #get data for each category
    plots[i].scatter(temp['Date'],temp['Count'])   #plot for that category
plt.show()   #show final generated plot
```

Above is python code, there might be some syntax error but it will give you an idea how to solve your problem and how to code.